# How to contain a radio group with React and HTML?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have n tasks, each containing many sets of radio buttons. If I select a `type` radio button in one task, it should not unselect the `type` in another task since they share the name `type`.

Forms are an obvious choice, but I may need to nest forms and nested forms dont obey our intentions.

I could set name to `type_x_y` where x and y are indices, so that they do not conflict, but this requires top-down indexing of objects just for radio groups.

I could set UUIDs for radio groups like `type_uuid`, but I guess they will trigger real HTML updates each time it is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

At all times, you should respect the rules of HTML form design. This will make your life easier, and it will make your pages accessible to specialized tools and plugins that you may not be thinking about when designing. I'm explaining this because you have already mentioned the solution to your problem: using the name of the radio button to enforce which other radio buttons are selected.

I'm not sure what you mean by "top-down indexing." Here is an example:

```
var choices = {
    favorite: {
        food: [pizza, steak],
        color: [blue, red]
    },
    hated: {
        food: [broccoli, tuna],
        color: [yellow, green]
    }
}

for (var category in choices) {
    for (var item in category) {
        for (var index in item) {
            var name = 'category_' + category + '_' + item;
            return <input type="radio" id={name} name={name} value={index}>
                       <label for={name}>{item[index]}</label>
                   </input>;
        }
    }
}
```

This is using JSX syntax, but the concept should apply to any template system that supports loops.